# Is there a way to evaluate this integral? What are the bounds on its solution set?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, constraints, multiple-integral

I came across this integral in a [problem I was trying to solve yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638098/hillary-clintons-iowa-caucus-coin-toss-wins-and-bayesian-inference/1638168): $$ \int_{0}^{b0}{\int_{0}^{b1}{\int_{0}^{b2}{\int_{0}^{b3}{\int_{0}^{b4}{\int_{0}^{b5}{\int_{0}^{b6}{\dfrac{(1-x_0)^6}{\sum_{n=0}^{6}2^n{6 \choose n}x_n^n(1-x_n)^{6-n}}dx_6 dx_5 dx_4 dx_3 dx_2 dx_1 dx_0}}}}}}} $$ where $b_n$ is the bound on the integral with respect to $x_n$.

Now, obviously the result of this integral depends on your choice of $b_n$s, but there are a few necessary restraints on the choices: $$ 0<b_n<1, \ \ b_0>b_1>\cdots>b_5>b_6, $$ and $$ \sum_{i=0}^{6} b_i = 1, $$

However, I'm really not experienced enough with integration of this complexity to have any idea where to go from here.

**Questions:**

Is there anyway to get a sense for the bounds on the output of this integral, or a distribution of possible solutions, using Monte Carlo methods, or some sort of numerical integration technique? Or maybe probabilistic methods? This seems far too complicated to have an analytic solution, but you people are amazing, so maybe I need to have more faith.

How might one even attempt to *start* tackling an integral of this nature analytically?

Comment: If any of the $b_m$ are zero then the integral is zero. And no, this has nothing to do with calculus of variations. If you want a numerical estimate, Monte Carlo would indeed be a good approach: sample $x_0,\dots,x_6$ uniformly from the prism $[0,b_0] \times \dots \times [0,b_6]$ many times, evaluate the integrand for each sample, then average the results of all your evaluations. A technique called importance sampling can accelerate convergence, but in this case I doubt it is really necessary.

Comment: Thank you, removed the question about CoV. With the Monte Carlo methods, I would just have to make sure that the bounds on the prism $ [0,b_0] \times \cdots \times [0,b_6] $ satisfy my restriction on the $b_n$s correct? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Monte Carlo would give you an estimate for a fixed sequence $b_0,\dots,b_6$, which you'd need to choose before starting.

Comment: Also, I think a closed form is hopeless: the innermost integral is something like $\frac{A}{B+Cx_6^6}$ (where $A,B,C$ depend on the other $x_i$), and, well, just look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%281%2Bx^6%29 Now imagine trying to insert the dependence on $x_5$ into the constants and having to integrate some function like that...

Comment: Wouldn't it be far more complicated than that? There would be six different variables to various powers in the denominator to integrate over

Comment: In the inner integral, the other 5 variables are constant, so it's as simple as that. But then you compute the inner integral and you get a very complicated integrand in the next integral.